# HTML Form needs to know how many records in DB

Tags: php, html, ajax, database, onchange

I have a HTML form (PHP), that has one or two checkboxes depending on what a user selects in a dropdown earlier in the form.  The problem is:

When a user selects an option from the dropdown, I need to access an SQL DB to find out how many records fit the query and if it exceeds a limit, only allow one checkbox, otherwise 2.

Pseudo:

```
Select location dropdown (populated by PHP/SQL );
If onchange.location has less than 50 records 
    show/enable 2 type checkboxes
else 
    show/enable one type checkbox
```

From the research I've done:

Using javascript to access server DB is a no-no,

Can't be done on client side using PHP.

Comment: you could lood at ajax. In [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm) you can find solution for your question.

Comment: Yep.  I think this is what I want. Quick question: Is there an ajax function for a onchange for a dropdown?

Comment: yes. And you can find it in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  And I got to learn a little Ajax along the way.  Works perfectly!  Thanks Alex!

Comment: accept the answer if it solved your problem, it will help other users also find the right answer faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user selects a user in the dropdown list, a function `showUser()` is triggered by the `onchange` event.

HTML Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

AJAX request sent to `getuser.php`, so you can do request to your DB.

Code of `getuser.php`:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']); // your sent parameter by AJAX

// do your request and process all needed info from DB.

?php>
```

You can find all needed info in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).